# zstd has no attribute 'compress'

Tags: command-line, software-installation, python3

I am getting this error when I was trying to run the command even though I've installed zstd latest version on Ubuntu. Can anybody help me with this?

[image: Terminal screenshot]

Comment: Hey Jhon! Instead of posting screenshot of terminal, I suggest you to copy the output of commands and paste them in the question directly.

Comment: Maybe you need to install the python wrapper to zstd ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create an instance of "compressor" first:

```
import zstandard

compressor = zstandard.ZstdCompressor()

input_data = b'11111'

compressed_data = compressor.compress(input_data)
Out[25]: b'(\xb5/\xfd \x05)\x00\x0011111'
```

https://python-zstandard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/compressor.html

Same goes for the decompression method...